# Crop empty arrays (padding) from a volume

Tags: python, numpy

What I want to do is crop a volume to remove all irrelevant data. For example, say I have a 100x100x100 volume filled with zeros, except for a 50x50x50 volume within that is filled with ones.
How do I obtain the cropped 50x50x50 volume from the original ?

Here's the naive method I came up with.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

test=np.zeros((100,100,100)) # create an empty 100x100x100 volume
rand=np.random.rand(66,25,34) # create a 66x25x34 filled volume
test[10:76, 20:45, 30:64] = rand # partially fill the empty volume

# initialize the cropping coordinates
minx=miny=minz=0
maxx=maxy=maxz=0
maxx,maxy,maxz=np.subtract(test.shape,1)

# compute the optimal cropping coordinates
dimensions=test.shape
while(tf.reduce_max(test[minx,:,:]) == 0): # check for empty slices along the x axis
    minx+=1
while(tf.reduce_max(test[:,miny,:]) == 0): # check for empty slices along the y axis
    miny+=1
while(tf.reduce_max(test[:,:,minz]) == 0): # check for empty slices along the z axis
    minz+=1
while(tf.reduce_max(test[maxx,:,:]) == 0):
    maxx-=1
while(tf.reduce_max(test[:,maxy,:]) == 0):
    maxy-=1
while(tf.reduce_max(test[:,:,maxz]) == 0):
    maxz-=1

maxx,maxy,maxz=np.add((maxx,maxy,maxz),1)
crop = test[minx:maxx,miny:maxy,minz:maxz]

print(minx,miny,minz,maxx,maxy,maxz)
print(rand.shape)
print(crop.shape)
```

This prints:

```
10 20 30 76 45 64
(66, 25, 34)
(66, 25, 34)
```

, which is correct. However, it takes too long and is probably suboptimal. I'm looking for better ways to achieve the same thing.

NB:

- The subvolume wouldn't necessarily be a cuboid, it could be any shape.
- I want to keep gaps within the subvolume, only remove what's "outside" the shape to be cropped.

Comment: in your example, you have a continuous area of 'relevant' data - what if you would have gaps in between?

Comment: Are you just trying to crop a numpy array? Why is tensorflow getting involved here?

Comment: @Dan I'm actually using this cropping functionality as part of a tensorflow network. But you're absolutely right, I could do without.

Comment: @MrFuppes Sorry if that wasn't clear. I want to keep gaps. I only want to remove the "surrounding" empty area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you wait for a sensible response (I would guess this is a builtin function in an image processing library somewhere), here's a way

```
y, x = np.where(np.any(test, 0))
z, _ = np.where(np.any(test, 1))
test[min(z):max(z)+1, min(y):max(y)+1, min(x):max(x)+1]
```

I think leaving tf out of this should up your performance.

---

Explanation (based on 2D array)

```
test = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, ],
    [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, ],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],
])
```

We want to crop it to get

```
[[1, 2]
 [3, 0]]
```

1. `np.any(..., 0)` this will 'iterate' over axis 0 and return `True` if *any* of the elements in the slice are [truthy](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html). I show the result of this in the comments here:

   ```
   np.array([
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],  # False
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, ],  # True
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, ],  # True
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],  # False
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ],  # False
   ])
   ```

   i.e. it returns `np.array([False, True, True, False, False])`
2. `np.any(..., 1)` does the same as step 2 but over axis 1 instead of axis zero i.e.

   ```
   np.array([
       [0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    ], 
       [0,     0,     1,     2,     0,    ],
       [0,     0,     3,     0,     0,    ],
       [0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    ],
       [0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    ],
   #    False  False  True   True   False
   ])
   ```

   Note that in the case of a 3D array, these steps return 2D arrays
3. (x,) = np.where(...) this returns the index values of the truthy values in an array. So `np.where([False, True, True, False, False])` returns `(array([1, 2]),)`. Note that this is a tuple so in the 2D case we would need to call `(x,) = ...` so `x` is just the array `array([1, 2])`. The syntax is nicer in the 2D case as we can use tuple-unpacking i.e `x, y = ...`
4. Note that in the 3D case, np.where can give us the value for 2 axes at a time. I chose to do x-y in one go and then z-? in the second go. The ? is either x or y, I can't be bothered to work out which and since we don't need it I throw it away in a variable named `_` which by convention is a reasonable place to store junk output you don't actually want. Note I need to do `z, _ =`  as I want the tuple-unpacking and not just `z =` otherwise `z` become the tuple with both arrays.
5. Well, this step is pretty much the same as what you did at the end of your answer so I assume you understand it. Simple slicing in each dimension from the first element with a value in that dimension to the last. You need the `+ 1` because slicing in python are not inclusive of the index after the `:`.

Hopefully that's clear?

Comment: Thank you. Your version seems to be the fastest. A short test on a 1000x1000x1000 volume yields 2.5s for you, 16s and 9s for @Alexander and 47s for Tensorflow. I'm a bit unclear about what you are doing though, would you mind explaining ?

Comment: @JMuller added an explanation in answer. Note I also took out the `> 0`s from the original answer as they weren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**(Edit)**
Oops, I hadn't seen [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326612/crop-empty-arrays-padding-from-a-volume/58330892#comment103020709_58326612) about keeping the so-called "gaps" between elements! This should be the one, finally.

```py
def get_nonzero_sub(arr):
    arr_slices = tuple(np.s_[curr_arr.min():curr_arr.max() + 1] for curr_arr in arr.nonzero())
    return arr[arr_slices]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. It is a lot slower than @Dan's proposal however (10s vs 2.8s).

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate! I'm currently working on a faster solution, i'm confident that I will find something.